# PIL image shows OK but saves black

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

Using PIL Image to binarize an image to optimize OCR shows **good results on-screen** but **saves all black** PNG. And when passing the image object to process with pytesseract it also returns no text...
Note: I don't really need to save the processed image as long as the OCR works.

```
basepath = 'img_bin/'
image_list = os.listdir(basepath)

for file in image_list:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, file)):
        print(file)

        img = Image.open(basepath+file).convert("L")
        
        img = ImageOps.invert(img)
       
        threshold = 20
        table = []
        pixelArray = img.load()
        for y in range(img.size[1]):  # binaryzate it
            List = []
            for x in range(img.size[0]):
                if pixelArray[x,y] > threshold:
                    List.append(0)
                else:
                    List.append(255)
            table.append(List)

        img = Image.fromarray(np.array(table))

        img.show()

        img.save(basepath+'processed.png')
        img_lines = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

        print(len(img_lines))
        print(img_lines)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
print(len(img_lines)) -> 1
print(img_lines)   -> <0x0c>
```

img.show():
[image]

saved 'processed.png'
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the image mode to RGB:

```
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save(basepath+'processed.png')
```

That's because the `save` method assumes RGB mode.

Comment: This works, but what if you want to write an image that is not in RGB mode?  e.g. you want to write a grayscale png?  Supposedly, according to the docs, Pillow should be able to write png from a variety of data modes, not just RGB https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png

Comment: A grayscale image can also be in RGB mode. For the images that are not RGB, the ```if``` statement will be true and the mode is changed to RGB. That was required by the save method a year ago.